# Can't Get Present Value Answer?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, finance

I've done this problem at least 20 times a number of different ways, but I can't seem to get the correct answer. Please show all work and describe the EXACT formula you used:

Find the present value of the ordinary annuity:
Payments of $78 are made quarterly for 10 years at 8% compounded quarterly.

Answer: $2133.73

Thanks!

> I used the formula PV = A(i)/1-(1+(i)^-nt) as directed by my teacher, but it still isn't coming out correctly.

Comment: Can you tell us what you did 1 or 2 of those 20 times? If you understand how an annuity is calculated, the solution is immediate, this isn't a tricky problem.

Comment: I used the formula PV = A(i)/1-(1+(i)^-nt) as directed by my teacher, but it still isn't coming out correctly.

Comment: Well then, it certainly seems as if the issue is that you are using the formula as directed instead of understanding how and why such a formula exists. I suggest writing down a cash flow diagram, the associated present value of the payments, and realizing you're summing a geometric series.

Comment: Thanks, you've been insanely helpful.

Comment: My only other pieces of advice are to make sure you are using the correct interest rate, and double checking your formula. 8% compounded quarterly is 2% effective quarterly, and I've never seen present value described as you have laid it out (see e.g. [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Present_value#Present_value_of_a_lump_sum))

Comment: The question I described to you is coming fresh off of a College Finite Math test review. The formula I mentioned came from my professor. I just need to know how to solve this to pass a test.

Comment: Maybe you are better at rote memorization than I am, but I've never been able to apply such a formula correctly under the pressure of an exam without first having gotten a pretty good grasp on _why_ it works. Since the formula as written appears to be incorrect, however, I have doubts that mere rote memorization will do very well for you.

Answer (score 1):

Let's go through the basics. You are receiving an annuity of $\$78$ each quarter for $40$ quarters. The interest rate is $8\%$ compounded quarterly, which is $2\%$ effective quarterly. Let $P_i$ denote the present value of the $i^{th}$ payment.

$P_1 = P(1+i)^{-1} = 78(1.02)^{-1}$

$P_2 = P(1+i)^{-2} = 78(1.02)^{-2}$

...

$P_{40} = P(1+i)^{-40} = 78(1.02)^{-40}$

The present value of the annuity is the sum of the above payments.

$\sum_{i = 1}^{40} P_i = 78\sum_{i = 1}^{40} (\frac{1}{1.02})^i = \frac{78}{1.02}\sum_{i = 0}^{39} (\frac{1}{1.02})^i = \frac{78}{1.02}\frac{1 - \frac{1}{(1.02)^{40}}}{1-\frac{1}{1.02}}$

where the $2^{\mathrm{nd}}$ equality is just to rewrite the series as the familiar geometric series and the final equality is applying the closed form solution for a geometric series solution.

Again, I'd recommend trying to understand the steps of the solution so you can understand *why* there is a formula for such equations and *what* it is, otherwise you can be led astray by wrong formulas (or even misusing correct formulas).